# Spring bean in a library must load before a bean in the "main" module

Tags: java, spring

I have two modules:
A and B
A is dependent on B

Each have a Spring bean:
A has bean_a
B has bean_b

However:
bean_b depends on bean_a, meaning bean_a must load 1st

In addition bean_b is a method which returns a bean_b.

So my code looks something like this:
Bean B definition

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("bean_a")
public BeanBClass getBeanB() {// Do something}
```

Module A application context:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="bean_a_package, bean_b_package"/>
<import resource="classpath*:module_b_context.xml"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            Some relevant property files
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bean_a" class="bean_a_package.bean_a_class">
    <property name="someProperty" value="${someProperty}"/>
</bean>
```

module_b_context.xml doesn't have anything relevant for the question and doesn't have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

And whenever I run my application I get the message:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'someProperty' in string value
>   "${someProperty}

Can I fix this somehow? I'm guessing that the order of bean loading doesn't work as I expected but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My immediate thinking is that 'someProperty' isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: As mikkel mentioned, it's probably not loaded by spring. A common error in this type of scenarios is that there's a typo in the path to the file that does contain the property, but the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` ignores the error as it's configured to ignore files that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response, everything worked fine until we added the dependency between the beans. It's not a typo

Comment: Whereabouts is `someProperty` defined? In a properties file in Module A?

Comment: Yes, the property is defined as it should be. Everything worked 100% until we added "dependson"